# IE10/Javascript + Touch device - How can i catch a double-tap?

Tags: javascript, touch, internet-explorer-10

I know there is an `MSGestureTap` event for a signle tap event, but is there anything similar for double-tap? (just like double-click).
Or should i measure the time gap between two tap events, and decide whether it was less than a given threshold?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using hammer.js library would probably save you a lot of hassle.  Otherwise with MSPointerDown and MSPointerUp events may get you a more accurate results and timing.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that it is also possible to register for the double click event, and it will do the work.